# Getting first free Id from DB

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Very often my code is returned on code review by other colleagues. I need explanation why second code is better than first.
Point is to get first empty Device Type Id from database in range predefined.
Device Type Ids can be:[1,2,4,10,11,12,14]
So if a range is from 10 to 20 predefined I want to get 13 because its first free Id.

So here is first code that do what it should:

```
firstFreeId = Enumerable.Range(_idRangeFrom.Value + 1, _idRangeTo.Value).First(i => !_dbContext.DeviceTypes.Any(dt => dt.DeviceTypeId == i));
```

Where _idRangeFrom and _idRangeTo are predefined ranges and _dbContext.DeviceTypes is a EF db Context that is a context of DB table DeviceTypes

Second code is:

```
var deviceTypeIds = _dbContext.DeviceTypes.Where(e => e.DeviceTypeId > _idRangeFrom.Value && e.DeviceTypeId < _idRangeTo.Value).Select(e => e.DeviceTypeId);
firstFreeId = Enumerable.Range(_idRangeFrom.Value + 1, _idRangeTo.Value).First(i => !deviceTypeIds.Any(dtId => dtId == i));
```

So my question is what I'm exactly getting with second code that I dont have in first?

Comment: Is this can bring problem in performances, because is hitting multiple times db?

Comment: You figured it out yourself indeed. The first code sample performs a database query per item in the range, until it hits the first free ID. The second sample performs one query and then figures the free ID client-side. Second approach will pretty much always be faster.

Comment: Both versions are bad. They hit database N-times.

Comment: In your second example, there should be a `.ToList()` after the select. That triggers the actual database query.

Comment: @JonasH Doesn't the first call of `.Any( ... )` on it in the second line have the same materializing effect?

Comment: @fildor Yes, but that is inside the loop, causing one query for each number checked. It would most likely be better to fetch all the numbers to the client side and do the intersection against memory instead of the database.  When I think about it, `.ToHashSet()` would be even better than .ToList

Comment: Do not try to find a “free ID” from a database then attempt to use it. That doesn't work; another user, stored procedure, or transaction can get the same ID. It also doesn't work with reserved IDs. Every modern DBMS comes with something like `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` that returns the ID of the record you just assigned. This works across users, procedures, and transactions.